# How do I make a taxonomy menu on a multisite with different links on different sites?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, domain-access

I have made genres using taxonomy that I want to appear in a menu in a multisite using the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module. The different sites will use different genres and is being used in a content type called Book. I want the menu to only show the genres that is being used by the books that are available on the site. What is the best way to make that happen?